# Prove $\mu$ is an outer measure, find the collection of all $\mu$-measurable sets and the necessary and sufficient conditions s.t. $\mu$ is a measure

Tags: measure-theory, outer-measure

I am trying to solve the exercise below. I have managed to prove that $\mu$ is an outer measure following the definition of outer measures ($\mu(\emptyset)=0$, monotonicity, $\sigma$-subadditivity). However, I am struggling to find $\mathcal{M}^*$, the collection of all $\mu$-measurable sets. It is clear that $\emptyset, X \in \mathcal{M}^*$ but I can't find more sets $A$, which satisfy $ \forall E \subseteq X \; \;  \mu(E) = \mu(E \cap A) +\mu(E \cap A^c)$. I also managed to prove that if an outer measure is finitely additive, it is a measure in general, but I can't find the sufficient and necessary conditions to prove that $\mu$ is a measure.

**Exercise:**
If $X \ne \emptyset$ and $\mu$ is a set function defined on $\mathcal{P}(X)$ as  \begin{equation}   \mu(X) =
    \begin{cases}
     \text{Card}(E), & \text{Card}(E) < \aleph_0\\
      \infty, & \text{Card(E)} \ge \aleph _0
    \end{cases}        \end{equation}
a) Prove that $\mu$ is an outer measure and find $\mathcal{M}^*$. 
b) Prove that if an outer measure is finitely additive, it is also a measure. Find the necessary and sufficient conditions under which the outer measure $\mu$ is also a measure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All subsets $A\subseteq X$ are $\mu$-measurable.  If $E\subseteq X$ then $E=(E\cap A)\sqcup(E\setminus A)$.  The cardinality of a disjoint union is always the sum of cardinalities, whether they're finite or not
$$
\operatorname{Card}(E)=\operatorname{Card}(E\cap A)+\operatorname{Card}(E\setminus A)\tag{1}
$$

If $E$ is finite, then all numbers in $(1)$ are finite and you get the conclusion $\mu(E)=\mu(E\cap A)+\mu(E\setminus A)$.

If $E$ is infinite then $\mu(E)=+\infty$.  Since an infinite set cannot be a union of two disjoint finite sets, either $E\cap A$ or $E\setminus A$ is an infinite set.  Therefore either $\mu(E\cap A)=+\infty$ or $\mu(E\setminus A)=+\infty$ (or both).  Either way $\mu(E)=\mu(E\cap A)+\mu(E\setminus A)$.

Comment: Thank you so much, this all makes sense! :) Do I understand correctly that according to this, $\mathcal{M}^* = \mathcal{P}(X)$, so $\mu$ outer measure is always a  measure on $\mathcal{P}(X)$? If this is true, what I don't understand is why a) doesn't ask for a proof of  $\mu$ being a measure, and why b) is asking for the necessary and sufficient conditions for something that is always true. Is my logic faulty somewhere or do you think this was simply a somewhat misleading question?

Comment: @wilma72:  It's possible to prove directly that $\mu$ is $\sigma$-additive on $\mathcal{P}(X)$.  I think the question just wanted to exercise the application of $\mu$-measurability on a relatively simple outer measure.